# Transformar html image em blob angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Tenho a seguinte imagem:

```
<img id="preview" class="cropped rounded-circle align-center animated fadeIn" width="220px" height="220px">
```

Preciso passar ela para uma função que vai converter em base 64, mas para converter para base 64, minha imagem deve estar em blob antes:
O que eu tentei:

```
  handleCropSelect(){
      var file = document.getElementById("preview")
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = this._handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  }
```

O que eu recebo:

> Argument of type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'Blob'.   Property 'size' is missing in type 'HTMLElement'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de algumas horas de pesquisa, consegui encontrar uma função que supre minha necessidade:

```
  getBase64Image(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
  }

  handleCropSelect(){
      var base64 = this.getBase64Image(document.getElementById("preview"));
      this.base64textString = base64;
  }
```